# SAS - matching and assigning matchid to the matching record

Tags: sas, matching

I have a data like below, one line for one person, there can be one or more persons having the same age and from the same area. I have one dataset with cases and one with possible controls, they look like this:

```
data cases;
input id age area matchid;
datalines;
0101 25 12 1 
0120 25 12 2 
0125 30 11 3 
0130 45 11 4 
0135 45 11 5 
;

data controls;
input id age area;
datalines;
0203 25 12 
0250 26 12 
0320 25 12 
1023 30 11 
3020 45 11 
2036 45 11 
3022 46 11 
0204 25 12 
0321 25 12 
1025 30 11 
3026 45 11 
2070 45 11 
;
```

Her is my code:

```
data control; set control;
check=1;
proc sort; by check; run;

data cohort; set case(where=(matchid=1)); 
   matchid=0; 
run;

%macro ccloop;
   %do i=1 %to &nobs;
data nowcase; set case(where=(matchid=&i)) end=final;
         case_id=id;
         case_age=age;
         case_area=area;
         check=1;
         drop id age area;
      proc sort data=nowcase; by check;
      data nowcase; merge nowcase control; by check; 
         if case_age=age and case_area=area;
         zzz=ranuni((667+&i));
      proc sort data=nowcase; by zzz; run;
      data nowcase; set nowcase; if _N_<=10; run;
      data casecase; set nowcase; 
         id=case_id;
         CASE=1;
         age=case_age;
         area=case_area;
         keep id case age area matchid;
      data casecont; set nowcase;
         CASE=0;
         keep id case age area matchid;
      data cohort; set cohort casecase casecont;
    dm log "clear";
   %end;
   data cohort; set cohort; if matchid=0 then delete;

%mend ccloop; run;

%ccloop; run;
```

I would like to finde 10 unik controls for each case and assign to the new dataset case=0 for controls and case=1 for cases and i want the controls to get the corresponding matchid from the case they are matched with. The problem with my code is that there are duplicates in the final dataset, I need help to adjust the code to avoid this or some tips to another way to do it.

The final dataset should look like this:

```
id age area matchid case
0101 25 12 1 1
0203 25 12 1 0
0120 25 12 2 1
0320 25 12 2 0
0125 30 11 3 1
1025 30 11 3 0
0130 45 11 4 1
3026 45 11 4 0
0135 45 11 5 1
2070 45 11 5 0
```

Here is an example with only one control for each case and I want to have 10 for each case and I only want one control to be “used” once - my main problem is that even though I have enough controls the same control is occurring more then once with a different cases.

Comment: Edited with data step code. Given this data, what does your desired result look like?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your expected output? What does the macro-variable `nobs` resolve to?

Comment: I wrote a reply to you guys as an answer- see below

Comment: Did you try PROC PSMATCH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use PROC PSMATCH?  Here is a solution using literally the first example in the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_psmatch_gettingstarted.htm).

```
data case_control;
  set cases controls;
  if missing(matchid) then type='CONTROL';
  else type='CASE';
run;

proc psmatch data=case_control region=cs;
   class type area;
   psmodel type(Treated='CASE')= age area;
   match method=optimal(k=1) exact=area distance=lps caliper=0.25;
   output out(obs=match)=Outgs lps=_Lps matchid=_MatchID;
run;

proc print data=outgs;
run;
```

[image: results]